# What is the concept or History behind Shakti Ganapati?

Tags: puranas, temple, ganesha, shakti

Shakti Ganapati is a concept wherein Ganesha is accompanied along with Shakti.

There are some modern temples especially in Southern India, which attribute Shakti as wife of Ganapati.

Even, the deity has Shakti (sitting on the left thigh of Vinayaka, i.e. Vama bhaga, which is normally attributed to place where wife is associated).

So, is there any proof in the Puranas regarding Shakti to be consort of Ganapati or Ganesha?

Comment: Shakti Ganapaty is one of the 16 forms of Ganapaty each one of whom is supposed to "rule" one of the 16 tithis.Shakti Ganapaty rules,for example, the panchami tithi.It does not connect Ganapty to Shakti like the way u are thinking.The 2nd answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I could find is [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8CRd.jpg) from the Narada Purana, which gives the Ganesha Gayatri Mantra along with the associated Dhyana Shloka for Ganesha:

> I meditate upon the deity who resembles the rising sun, who is the cause of maintenance and dissolution of the world.  **He is accompanied with Shakti**, well-adorned and has lifted up chakra (discus) and tooth (danta).

This should be taken with a grain of salt though, because the Narada Purana is considered to have a lot of interpolations, and because references to Ganesha in ancient Hindu scripture are few and far between, since he only rose to popularity later on.

In any case, I doubt that this Shakti is Parvati; it may just be the Shakti or energy of Ganesha.

Comment: So, worship of Ganesa, with Shakti sitting on this left thigh is valid. Because, there are many creating temples for Shakti (parvati) sitting on left thigh (which means she is his wife) in some parts of South India...Height of blasphemy...

Comment: @Krishna I doubt it's Parvati sitting on his thigh.  It may just be his own Shakti or energy.

Comment: So, how do you say so? So, same should be logic used for Lakshmi Ganapati also.

Comment: Normally, Siddhi and buddhi are considered consorts or shakti of Ganesa. But, in south India of late they have started new deities like Shakti Ganapati and Lakshmi Ganapati, confusing gullible people

Comment: @Krishna Well, Shakti Ganapati at least seems to have a basis in the Narada Purana.  I doubt Lakshmi Ganapati has any scriptural basis.

Comment: @Krishna Since Ganesha only became popular later on, a lot of customs associated with Ganesha were made up by people rather than having a scriptural basis.  Like did you know that celebration of Ganesha Chaturthi is less than 500 years old?  Hindu scripture doesn't mention when Ganesha was born, so the date may have originated in folklore.

Comment: Why the  down vote?

Answer (score 3):

there are 112 forms of ganapati...each with different attribute....shakti ganapati is one of the 32 forms of ganesha....here shakti is shakti of ganesha which is maya shakti ( hreem) represented as beejakshara in shakti ganesha mantra....she is not parvathi....in laksmi ganapati form the lakshmi is not mahalakshmi.., instead she is siddha laksmi( another name vallabha ), siddha lakshmi is mayashakti of mahaganapati( vallabha ganapati)....the term shakti refers to any goddess according to mantra shastra...shakti can be lakshmi, or bhuvaneswari or saraswathi or any goddess....in temples idols are installed with elaborative rituals based on agama sastras...even small mistake will not occur...there are hundreds of books there which speak volumes about these rituals and upasana

Comment: Your answer is correct.But can u cite from some Scriptures?This site gives 16 Ganapatys one per each Tithi.http://www.agasthiar.org/AUMzine/0012-ganapathi.htm...

Comment: Which Scriptures talk about the 32 Ganeshas?